# Is it possible to turn off type check for certain functions

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I've got a decorator:

```
return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor): void {
        const originalMethod = descriptor.value

        if (!schema) return originalMethod

        schema(types)

        descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
            return originalMethod.apply(this, args)
        }
    }
```

and I initiate the schema like this:

```
@endpoint({ 
    schema: (types) => ({
        test: 'test',
        test2: 'test2',
    })
})
```

I always need to assign the type:

[image: types error]

Is it possible to somehow specify it may be in the decorator or any other way to avoid it without using `// @ts-ignore`

**UPDATE**

This is the decorator declaration

```
export function endpoint({ schema }: { schema: any, path?: string }) {
    
    return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor): void {
        const types: any = Joi.types()
        const originalMethod = descriptor.value

        if (!schema) return originalMethod

        descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
            const context: any = { ...this, ...target, methodName: propertyKey }

            try {
                const { error } = schema.call(context, types, Joi).validate(args[0], { abortEarly: false })

                if(error) {
                    return {
                        type: 'ValidationError',
                        code: 422,
                        errors: error.details.map((err: any) => err.message)
                    }
                }
    
            } catch(err: any) {
                return {
                    type: 'InternalError',
                    code: 500,
                    errors: err.message,
                }
            }

            return originalMethod.apply(this, args)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using it like this at the moment, where I always need to provide the type, but I would like to just do like this to save time because I already know what type there should be 100% and maybe there is an option to set the type as a predefined one for that particular place.

It would sure make the code shorter and faster dev experience

```
    @endpoint({
        schema: ({ object, string }: any) => object.keys({
            name: string,
            description: string,
            category: string.optional(),
        })
    })
```

[Link where you can find the playground with the main idea](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKQsOAzKERwOQCtnYBQhqArgHYDGMwE5cApuQCaTDkwAUA3nAM6UAFgxABDOAF8AXHF4DhYmaPIBPADRwwomIID8MvjCjsA5pICUswnBtxrtqAxiko9MlRp04nGKKgmnJVUNMAwwBlgVAGkGFQMjUw1mBgFjMBhoGQAFMIiYFQARFMo0jKhzGQA3ZGYrW3q4SjpDOHzwviCVOABeRGQAOjaUznN7Bsbm%20GhgE3ZRABsAWSdBCFre5NTgdOh%20yoXSBmJxm2BUbwBCeRFRS0dnVzhp2fIF5Z0145PNku2yvYODB6aAo1Fo9E4-ShfhMHTgyhUAG0ALqWbhjE42JrkFrYmAMAAeME6wN4UMGgmAfA05N8-icGhAKzWADlREyZKEIOFIjEuhIvpibEYuuihSdsS1eBEMFBJMDrmJ%20pQFvNOHjCTANENqX1gOYAfNgMxtAxODC%20IiAAzIjS8UQAI2gMAAon55nE0As%20ECJKMMeLTqhODLoGiA4H6vcXPQxZHA0MZNgAGoLY3acEuqCy7BqCPxhpNZIyAAsACYy3mC%20LQ1A4bX%20slfMB5nx%20mIwJwQ9nOpZugA%20RjZ9spPiiAKjasNAVTme2fPTxraITdqC9urV6OPONT4UqcJJgCSHAir3mWZzVd3WLWDBkAFYrVar9fa-Xh0y%20GOAi-43PxQKC5Rk4MZPMYLxvMyzD9KIYBgB6PiUrqFqTic-6SIQgGUPMohfnAAAqKTwOiGIAAJMKwyAcDwC6KqIMg8E8Dq4Aw1AaIYxjkGYfo9IOEDMaxMD9AA1rEfA0ZG9H8AkXHtqIBKcAAjFa5i-piDrxJxJj9NynhniMam2H6GLGfU%20KGMsIxWAuW6xkBtiJnAAAGADCEAQPMTmGeMn7fnezkAPLCV59k3sWcBlk%203kYSZxBYZMjTAuQDAAO4EURIzEJQgxEZZO6tERSbkBA8A6BEDC5phoxAA)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/WK7GGW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Comment: @jcalz I provided that same code above but included the image so that people can visually understand the idea of the problem I am facing. I thought it's a trivial thing and not a but that it worth making a reproduction of the real code somewhere in the playground but I can make it. The issue here - minimize the amount of code in certain functions. That was the key idea)

Comment: If the problem you're facing has anything to do with that red error squiggle then that information is not in plaintext in the question itself.  Also you should probably include the error *message*, and indeed all information necessary for others to reproduce the issue.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz Thanks! The 'error' just says - Binding element 'string' implicitly has an 'any' type. So, I just need to explicitly set the type for current arg as `(arg: string) => {...}`. but I just wanted to avoid it (turn this off for the current place in the code) in that certain decorator. I thought there is an option for that except `// @ts-ignore`

Comment: But anyway thanks for being around! @jcalz

Comment: Please provide the _whole_ declaration of the `@endpoint` decorator as well as one full example of the usage of that decorator including what is being decorated. The types in the code you've omitted matter a lot here.

Comment: @AlexWayne Thanks for the comment! I've added the code and a link to a playground. So far I should always set type by myself or use `// @ts-ignore` but I would better like to tell Typescript in one place somewhere what it should be and then just use it using short arrow function like in plain JS. I am not sure if it's possible in TS but it would be comfortable @jcalz the link in the update maybe it'll be easier to catch the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't typically need to type callback function arguments manually, but in this case you have many things here typed as `any` which should not be.

If you type `schema` properly, everything seems to work very well.

I don't know `Joi` at all, but I derived the following type for the `schema` function from your example:

```
type SchemaFn = (
    types: ReturnType<typeof Joi['types']>,
    joi: typeof Joi
) => Joi.ObjectSchema<any>
```

Which you can then use like so:

```
function endpoint({ schema }: { schema: SchemaFn, path?: string }) {
  //...
}
```

With that, this code has no type errors.

```
class Test {
    @endpoint({
        schema: ({ object, string }) => object.keys({
            a: string.max(10),
            b: string.optional(),
        })
    })
    testMe() {
        return {
            type: `Cool`,
            message: `Ok`,
            code: 200,
        }

    }
}
```

And even better than having no errors, `object` and `string` here are strongly typed. So you get intellisense and type checking on your usage of those values.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKQsOAzKERwOQCtnYBQhMAnmAKZwDKAxgBYUgCGAYgHZwC8cAFIXEFwylAM4AuOACUKMAK5R2AFXIUAPCIoRUiZAG1sm0dgC6APgA0AofmCTN23cEIBKbmacA6APIAjXBS0MHSMLGrM7KRmxKhy7EHAEJwU7AAmkMDsMLwA3nCiDEzMcAC+knkFocySIUUcFnBgzDD0APySojBQmQDmpW451oJQsgqcsfEwiZy8MMxQPbKSEaQNYBiUsKQA0hSkHV29DakUBd1gMNCSAAobFFsAIqe055dQLpIAbsipcINCALgtCSnWEqlE3C8Rl4LiGgOB7FB0GAPUyzAANgBZWT0CC-HgnM7AC7QTyfDFyCjEQFCYA6XgAQkqRTcI3kijgyNR7Ax2JaeOpNLghJexLeZIpVB4EwSST4ngV8x6EjgKz0JgGcKFQJB8ARMAoAA8YMtIpC8grPC1gKIGpa5gtZA0QDi8QA5ZguyTrCCbMi7UilQXawRdQP-EM0hGgvL3DBQUqQ5ksTy0DHo3j6o0wBpGBpIYAuCXo4CpZoUXhK0R6AAMJgaeWYvmgMAAovN0fs0BjRFQSrCtZG4HTeHHoJqhyG2WM-oPJzTNJJsAA1DGl5rTVtQePYKzzofAk6SAAsACZT3v9yGx1AVTfPCc5sB0aJPCwwLxR9vTaQ3FwPHGb6nKIzCLLCV6AiUc4hlBALQQCJRAs0DBflAP4Tle04chGEGhqoS4AJJZPcPLoluO6XrhOpHnAACsNY1pRuE3ne25AaIIGLExk6wUOUHwUIWGcFyaJYq6qSeMwYBgJ2sz0DaDRVuBQq8YIUH8bQ6LMBxcBKKc8A4XAAACKTpMgWS5NBybVHweQQP4gQ5vkhzsH0-buJyDlBJ4ADWeyiJZk42Z03SuW+zCGrwACMNYuNxQq+AcoU9J4vpTEkGIwvFanKTlcIGp02IwrO2pCSVQ6LnAAAGADCEAQOiVXZYCLocaBFCSFV3g+U1AmCIeHVwKeDHNfxCGEBpupApC7AUAA7rp+kwsQtBWvpRWGQVJo4OwEDwC09wULuE2wkAA)

Comment: Thank you a lot, Alex! Yes, I definitely should fix typing everywhere but as you can see I am not still good at typings)) I have never even used `ReturnType` before)) So, as I got right, it was asking for clarification because I everywhere used any type, right?

Comment: Typescript _really_ likes for function arguments to to have strong types. Your function didn't because of that `any`. So Typescript's error was reminding you to add them. You should try avoid the `any` type at all costs since it basically turns off Typescript anywhere that it's used, and that makes your code less sound.

Comment: Thanks again! I'll be playing around with that now